# Use of getline to parse and store variables

Tags: c++, parsing, while-loop, savestate

I'm writing a simple sandbox text-based game in c++ and have just got around to save files. Having looked at a few of the questions on this site and others I opted to do my own rather that use the boost libraries etc.

My save code works fine however, my load code isn't working like I want!

```
int loadGame(string filename){
string delim=":";
string readline;

ifstream filestream;
filestream.open(filename.c_str());

while(getline(filestream,readline)){
    cout << readline << endl;
    stringstream linestream(readline);
string         data;
getline(linestream, data, ':');
linestream >> playername >> location[0] >> location[1] >> hitpoints >> coins >> axes >> swords >> food >> maps;
}
return 0;
}
```

It currently loops, as you would expect but then stores only the last 'maps' variable to playername.
I understand that the `while(getline(filestream,readline)){` is the cause of the problem but as a newbie I can't see how to work around this without adding in a loop with lots of ifs that does an
(pseudo code)

```
while(n<10){
if n=1{ linestream >> playername}
if n=2{linestream >> location[0]...
```

which seems to me to be very drawn out and inefficient.

A sample save might look like this:

```
playername:John
location[0]:400
location[1]:840
hitpoints:100
coins:35
axes:0
swords:0
food:0
maps:3
```

I know this is probably badly worded but I'd appreciate any help on this problem. Thanks in advance.
ps any other tips on the code posted here would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're beginning with C++, there are a couple of tips I could give you.

First of all, don't bother with parsing. There are far more interesting things to do with your time. Choose an easier input format, like

```
playername John Doe
hitpoints 300
```

Notice that I'm using a white space to separate the value from the key. Now you can simply do something like:

```
std::string key, value;
while (<more input>)
{
    input_file >> key;
    std::getline(input_file, value);

    if (key == "playername")
        // whatever...
    else if (key == "maps")
        // stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just played around with it and it seems to be working now. And thanks for saving me from the clutches of parsing :L

Answer (score 1):

In the loadGame function you are checking unknown "arg" to string "null", not NULL.

Comment: I've removed the unrelated code you mentioned the variable 'arg' was from a separate function. Also, null was a potential input for that variable so wasn't as incorrect as it looked!

Comment: In that case checkout following one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971593/c-getline-and-file-eof